# how to use xmgrace to plot histogram from a plot

Tags: xmgrace

I have a text file (say, sample1.dat) with two columns:first column is a serial no running from 1 to 5000 and second column consists of 5000 dihedral angles varying in between -180 to 180 in degree. By using the command

```
xmgrace sample1.dat
```

I got a plot of dihedral angle vs.serial no.

To get the histogram from the plot, I did the following in the pop up window of Grace: `Data ->  Trasnformation -> Histograms`

In the newly pop up window called `Grace: Histograms`, I selected the `source` graph but did not select any in the `destination` graph as explained somewhere in grace tutorials. After selecting start as -180, stop as 180 and number of bins as 5 and then hitting the `Accept` command in that window, I got the following error message:

```
[Error] Please select single source and destination graphs
```

Help me to get the histogram from the plot. I want to use `xmgrace` to plot the histogram. I know how to plot it using some widely used plotting tools like gnuplot and others.

Comment: Why is this tagged R???

Comment: I also use R. I tagged it thinking some of R people are smart to help in this issue. Is any harm in such tagging?

Answer (score 8):

You nearly had it! Here is a full step-by-step solution:
Save the data in a two-column file "sample.dat". Here are the contents of such a file:

```
#n  angle
1   13
2   -162
3   -63
4   53
5   -170
6   80
7   173
8   39
9   113
[ etc ...]
```

In my example file I have 40 entries with randomly-generated angles. 
Call xmgrace from the command line and load the data file:

```
xmgrace sample.dat
```

At first you will see a line plot of angle vs n. We can bin the data and plot a histogram as follows:

```
Data > Transformations > Histograms
```

This will open a new window titled "Grace: Histograms". Right-click on your data set "G0.S0" and duplicate it. On the left-hand panel select the original data set by left clicking once. On the right-hand panel select the new data set "G0.S1".

Now at the bottom of the window choose your binning parameters.

```
Start at: -180

Stop at: 180 

# of bins: 5.
```

Click `Apply`. The histogram is now plotted but the original line plot needs to be hidden. In the left-hand panel right-click on the original data set "G0.S0" and choose "hide".

After all of these steps the "Histograms" window should now look like this:

[image: Grace Histograms window]

Finally, in the main xmgrace window, rescale the plot. 
You should now see the histogram, with your angles binned into five bins. The angle ranges are shown on the x axis and the frequency of each bin range on the y axis. Here is the default output where I have labelled the axes:

[image: output image]

The total of the frequencies from all bins should add up to the number of data lines in sample.dat.

Comment: Is it also possible to calculate the mean value from such a histogram?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'mean value from a histogram', but mean value of the source data can be calculated using `Data->Feature Extraction` and selecting the `Feature` `Y average`. Of course, this does not use the histogram.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you don't need the first column. The data file can also be a one-column file, xmgrace will interpret it as the first column was implicitly 1,2,3,4...

Comment: @feedMe Is it possible to do all these steps on the command line ?